# Linq ForEach, Async Await differences

Tags: linq, async-await

Can someone tell me the difference between the 2 approaches below and why they have different results? I would have thought that method 2 was just an exploded version of method 1. I've clearly missed some key differentiating detail. What is it?

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    Task<List<Result>> ExecuteAsync();
}

public async Task Execute(List<Result> results, IEnumerable<IStrategy> strategies)
{
    // Approach 1, strategy will return 1 result, results collection will be empty at method exit
    strategies.ForEach(async strategy => results.AddRange(await strategy.ExecuteAsync()));

    // Approach 2, strategy will return 1 result, results collection will have one result at method exit
    foreach (var strategy in strategies)
    {
       results.AddRange(await strategy.ExecuteAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `ForEachAsync` and `await` that?

Comment: @DavidG that would only be possible if OP can pass an `IQueryable<IStrategy>` instead of an `IEnumerable<IStrategy>`.

Comment: @RenéVogt D'oh, of course. I probably forgot because I never use either of those methods, nasty hacks and rarely any benefit over using a plain `foreach`

Comment: @RenéVogt Actually, is there even a `ForEach` for `IEnumerable<T>` anyway? I don't think there is...

Comment: @DavidG oh, right... OP? How does this code compile? What is that `ForEach` method you call on an `IEnumerable<IStrategy>`?

Comment: @RenéVogt I still think your answer is correct though, perhaps could do with an addendum that if you put a delay after the `Execute` method that the `results` list will then contain the correct content.

Comment: @René updated original post to show IStrategy definition.

Comment: @DavidG I can try that of course, thanks. I'd still like to know the difference between the two approaches though.

Comment: @user1054637 The point is `IEnumerable<IStrategy>` does not have a instance- or extension method called `ForEach`. Are you sure `strategies` is an `IEnumerable<IStrategy>` or is it actually a `List<IStrategy>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>.Foreach()` takes an `Action<T>`. The lambda you try to pass to `ForEach` is converted by the compiler into a *state-machine*, the call returns immediatly while you `await` the inner `strategy.ExecuteAsync()` call.

So `ForEach` *thinks* your lambda has finished although it actually still waits for `strategy.ExecuteAsync()`. `ForEach` is not able (or desgined) to `await` that method (the delegate can not even return a `Task` to `await`).
So it iterates to the next `strategy` without waiting for the previous `ExecuteAsync()`. Finally `ForEach` returns and you don't know if all (or any at all) of the strategies have been executed completely, they may still be running.

If you would wait a little longer after your first approach returns, your `results` list should be filled correctly (but of course that's **not** the way you should do it! Your second approach is the correct way).

---

The second approach works, because you always `await` the `ExecuteAsync()` and only then continue to iterate. So after the `foreach` loop all strategies have been executed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.